# VSCode Platform-specific Command in Tasks

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to set up cross-platform tasks to use different commands on different platforms, similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189261/setting-up-platform-specific-default-tasks-in-vs-code) or [this tutorial](https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editor/tasks/#operating-system-specific-properties).

This is my `.code-workspace` file:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "tasks": {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "Run",
                "windows": { "command": "${workspaceFolder}/webui-user.bat" },
                "linux": { "command": "${workspaceFolder}/webui.sh" },
                "type": "process",
                "group": "none",
            },
            {
                "label": "Open UI",
                "windows": { "command": "explorer" },
                "linux": { "command": "xdg-open" },
                "type": "process",
                "args": ["http://127.0.0.1:7860/"],
                "group": "none",
            }
        ]
    },
    "settings": {
        ...
    },
    "launch": {
        ...
    },
}
```

However, VS Code complains about the `Missing property "command".` and the tasks don't appear in the task list. How do I properly define platform-specific commands?

Comment: What happens if you add `command: "echo didnt work"`?

Comment: Huh, after restarting VSCode the tasks now appear in the task list and run properly, even when I remove the `"command": "echo didnt work"`. Although VS Code does still complain about the missing properties when I open the workspace file.

Comment: I did recommend to add it exactly so it stops complaining